# Get a list of rows showing the average found for each year MYSQL

Tags: mysql, database

so I've searched and found a lot of questions similar to mine such as 
[MYSQL - get a row for each year, with total sum for each month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8960759/mysql-get-a-row-for-each-year-with-total-sum-for-each-month) but I was looking for a different way. I'm using the Lahman database and finding the top ten players by WAR each year. I'm then averaging those players ages to give the average age for that season. I'm trying to do this for every year but I'm stuck on how to do that.

```
SELECT AVG(t.age) As AverageAge, w.yearID
    FROM (SELECT w.playerID, w.age
    From war_batting w, Master m
    WHERE w.playerID = m.playerID AND w.yearID = 2012
    ORDER by w.WAR desc
    LIMIT 10) t, 
war_batting w;
```

This displays the average of the top 10 players for that season so I'm looking to do that for every season. In the post I linked to I see they do it for every value they need but I'm looking for a way that doesn't involve repeating the same code for almost 150 years. I've programmed in Java and C++ before so naturally I'm looking for a way to loop through what I have and just keep adding 1 to the year ID up until the current year. I'm struggling to understand just how to do this. This code above also returns the yearID as 2004 and not 2012 but I'm more confident in my ability to fix that as I'm pretty sure I have in other tests. Also if the code block doesn't come out well when I first post this I'll try and fix it as this is my first post here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not selecting anything from `master` table so there's no need to join with it..

Try the below query.  It has an inner query that uses user-defined variables to rank based on WAR descending.  Then the outer query only looks at ranks that are <= 10, and then it averages while grouping by yearID.

```
SELECT AVG(T.age) AS AverageAge, T.yearID
FROM 
  (SELECT w.playerID, w.age, w.yearID,
         CASE WHEN @prev_year = yearID THEN @rank := @rank+1
         ELSE @rank:=1
         END as rank,
         @prev_year := yearID
    FROM war_batting w
    ORDER BY yearID ASC, WAR DESC
   )T
WHERE T.rank <= 10
GROUP BY T.yearID
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d3c43/5)

This way you can just add `ORDER BY T.yearID DESC` or `ORDER BY T.yearID ASC` to the end of your query and get all your result without executing the same code for each year for 150 years.

Comment: The master was left over from a different code but yes I do not need that. As for your sample it goes through the years but the values for average Age for each year are all incorrect. I'm not sure why but I'll see if I can work with this to get exactly what I need.

Comment: I'm honestly not sure why, but when I remove the w.playerID = m.playerID in the where statement in a test that finds the values for just one year, it only returns the number 1 player's age. In this case of showing the top ten players it will also just display him 10 times.

Comment: I just tried adding this statement and the Master table back in to your program and now it works perfectly. I'm still not entirely sure why it works this way but thank you so much for your help!

Comment: the join would make sense only if war_batting table contains playerids that aren't in master... maybe that's your case here. but i am glad you figured it out